# recipient_bcc_maps operating for unknown recipients

Tags: postfix-mta

My system is using postfix with amavisd-new. I need to have a copy of all valid incoming mail so I have a recipient_bcc_maps statement with a regexp in main.cf that does the job without having to maintain a long list of addresses.  The problem is that this also bcc's for unknown recipients.  Where would be a better place to put the recipient_bcc_maps statement (for example, in master.cf) so it only operates for known receipients?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a different approach.  I used check_recipient_access on the server holding the email copies and set smtpd_recipient_restrictions so that the action for 'restrictive' was REJECT.  In the recipient_access hash table I set all the address I wanted to reject to restrictive.  That way I kept all the historical emails for certain addresses but preventied new emails being added.